# Is there any logical purpose for this javascript beyond what I can evaluate?

Tags: javascript

Here are the snippets from one of our pages.  It's my opinion that this is terribly complex, confusing, and flawed in it's design.  For one thing, it causes a message in IE that the page is trying to access the clipboard.  Is there something I'm missing?

**I guess my question is; Is it okay to think that this is complete overkill?  Do I have a right to be frustrated?  Or am I oblivious to some higher knowledge?**

```
function NoEmailGiven(){

    var copyval

    document.frm1.NoEmail.focus();
    document.frm1.NoEmail.select();
    copyval=document.SCPACALL.NoEmail.createTextRange();
    copyval.execCommand('Copy');
    document.frm1.Email1.focus();
    document.frm1.Email1.select();
    document.execCommand('Paste');
    document.frm1.Email2.focus();
    document.frm1.Email2.select();
    document.execCommand('Paste');

}

response.write "<INPUT TYPE=button name=NoEmail VALUE=""None"" Title=""Click if No Email Address"" ONCLICK=""NoEmailGiven""></td></tr>"
```

- Here is what the page is supposed to do..

If the user clicks the button labeled "Click here if no email address" then auto populate Email1 & Email2 with the literal string 'None'

- Here is the pseudocode as I have figured it out from the page usage of what it **actually** does.

If the user clicks the button labeled "Click here if no email address" copy the value of this button which is "None" into the client's clipboard, then paste from the clipboard into Email1 & Email2

- **Finally: What I would have written** (Only to duplicate the process, not improve or change the form to the users)

  `function NoEmailGiven()
  {
      Email1.value = "None";
      Email2.value = "None";
  }`

Comment: Wow. You should send this to The Daily WTF.

Comment: That's enough JavaScript to feed a small army...  Yes, whoever wrote this needs a spanking.

Comment: I hope it's understood that my basic assumption when reviewing my predecessors code is that he did it for a reason I may not understand.  I want to understand the rationale as to not undo anything that was done for a truly legitimate reason.

Comment: nah I'll use the DailyWTF for his homebrew encrypt decrypt algorithm....encrypt(x) =   (x-1237)/17

Comment: If I found that <airquote>encrypt</airquote> function I would stop assuming "that he did it for a reason I may not understand".

Comment: @StephenP Kudos for your use of html style finger quotes....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is a stupid way to do this. They obviously didn't know what they were doing and have not realised that copy and paste is a user orientated concept, whereas copying the value of one field to another using code more sense.

I'd delete it and rewrite it!

Comment: Oh, i'd love..LOVE...to show some other developers in the who are in the 'know' all the things I see...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that what they're trying to do is copy data from one field to another. In jQuery, that would be:

```
var NO_EMAIL = '.....';
function NoEmailGiven() {
    $('#Email1').val(NO_EMAIL);
    $('#Email2').val(NO_EMAIL);
}
```

Comment: I agree. But why would anyone ever do it the way it is implemented above using the clipboard?  Also, I think JQuery is overkill for something as simple as this....but I also could be wrong there.